# Values of auth is inconsistency in middleware plugin Nuxt 3

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I am very new in Nuxt 3 and need advice. I currently developing a Nuxt project which uses Firebase Auth, I following this tutorial [tutorial Nuxt 3 Firebase auth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NoJa7FKqmhU&t=77s), and everything has gone well so far. But when I am implementing router guard (I using plugin middleware for auth), the problem occurs. The problems are shown in this picture.

[image: image1]

the `currentUser` is null? however when I console log `$auth` value the `currentUser` exists. my Code for this middleware is as follows:

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
    addRouteMiddleware('global-test', () => {

    }, { global: true })

    addRouteMiddleware('auth', async() => {

        const { $auth } = useNuxtApp()


        console.log("call auth middle 1", $auth);

        console.log('call auth middle 2', $auth.currentUser);
    })
})
```

Here is the detail of my first console log

[image: imagw2]

Please help

**Note: I am using Nuxt `3.9.3`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the route guards can trigger before $auth becomes available to nuxt (nuxtApp). Instead of calling $auth within in a route guard try this ( I included it in the same file as my firebase client plugin).:

```
nuxtApp.vueApp.provide("auth", auth);
nuxtApp.provide("auth", auth);
nuxtApp.vueApp.provide("firestore", firestore);
nuxtApp.provide("firestore", firestore);

let userFromState = useFirebaseUser();
async function IsLoggedIn() {
    try {
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
            auth.onAuthStateChanged(
                (user) => {
                    if (user) {
                        // Yes User is signed in.
                        userFromState.value = user;
                        console.log("plugins", userFromState.value);
                        resolve("User is there");
                    } else {
                        // No user is not signed in.
                        reject("There is no user");
                    }
                },
                // Prevent console errors
                (error) => reject(error)
            )
        );
        return true;
    } catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
}

await IsLoggedIn();
```

Firebase says [the recommended way to get the current user is by setting an observer on the Auth object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).

The function IsLoggedIn() essentially returns a promise that resolves when $auth has loaded. It also assigns the firebase user to a nuxt composable I created in /composables called useFirebaseUser().

```
export const useFirebaseUser = () => useState<User | null>("firebaseUser", () => null);
```

Once the reactive composable becomes populated with user data, I can reference to it in nuxt route middleware. The plugin will execute globally first, wait for $auth to resolve, and execute before the route middleware does.

Comment: I found a very useful thread that shed light on this, but i cannot find it any more. If anyone knows what I am talking about please link so i can credit!

Comment: Are you call this `IsLoggedIn` in Plugins/firebase where initializeApp is called?

Comment: yes, i understand now. I use your solution and added some tricky. But the core solution is by wrapping onAuthStateChanged with Promise. I accept you solution, thank you